# Is there a word "issual"?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, subcontinental-english

I have used and come across the phrase "issual of tickets" but when recently writing something my Word dictionary tells me that "issual" is not an actual word.

Is that the case?

Comment: More common in most English speaking regions would be "issuance of tickets".

Comment: @Pieter: Indeed. And as my charts show, the rise of *issuance* neatly parallels the decline in *issual* (which was never really "correct", but originally there wasn't really an established alternative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would make more sense to just say there *was* such a word...

[image]

Apparently that graph represents only [about 8020 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22issual%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so it was never that much used anyway.

---

In case you have trouble accessing the 2 links posted by @Siva (I did), here they are again...

> 1: [Times Of India](http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Default/Layout/Includes/MIRRORNEW/ArtWin.asp?From=Archive&Source=Page&Skin=MIRRORNEW&BaseHref=PMIR/2011/01/07&ViewMode=HTML&PageLabel=7&EntityId=Ar00700&AppName=1)
>   *Staff shortage at Food Distribution Office hampers timely **issual** of ration cards.*
>
> 2: [Anna University "blog" page](http://www.chennaiuniversity.net/2013/11/anna-university-hall-ticket-internals-nov-dec-jan-2013-2014.html)
>    *The web portal for Hall ticket **issual** process is open and the students will get their hall tickets soon.*
>
> 3: [Vanuatu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanuatu) [Cultural Centre website](http://www.mol.gov.vu/lands-lm-lease-preparation-process.php)
>    *This process usually ensues [sic] the **issual** of a Negotiator Certificate and acquiring a Survey Plan.*

I added one more, but it wasn't easy to find instances that weren't just blogs, chat, or Q&A sites. The second one is particularly embarrassing. I'm not sure even Indian English could endorse the lack of a definite article before *"Hall ticket issual process"* or the inclusion of same before *"students"*. And the apparently random switch between *"Hall"* and *"hall"* seems indefensible. Things get much worse looking at more text in the link. (If that's representative of Anna University, it's bad there! :)

---

For most purposes most people would say *issual* is a pointless variant of ***issue***, but obviously there are *some* contexts where the writer genuinely wants a "bigger" noun to convey *multiple individual acts of issuing* (the ToE context). Other times it's just poor writers trying to sound more "official".

But as this chart shows, a century ago when Anglophones in general realised they needed a word for the context erroneously addressed by ToE above, they went for ***issuance***...

[image]

As has been commented, someone has [proposed to Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/1038/ISSUAL) that they should include the word, citing that very same ToE usage as evidence that it *"has been in use for some time now in India"*. But so far as I'm concerned, that person (just the ToE journalist trying to justify himself?) is mistaken, and Collins won't resuscitate this moribund word - which isn't even accepted by OED, despite having been much more common in the past (usually their speciality).

---

TL;DR: It was a (rare) word, but it's way past its sell-by date, and won't be revived even in India.

Comment: I hope you're right-   it's a terrible word.

Comment: @Jim: I've spent over half an hour looking into this, and I'd be pretty certain I've got to the bottom of it. But until I found this page and started downvoting all those manifestly incorrect answers, collectively they had more votes than Andrew's (which is correct so far as it goes, but doesn't really explain or justify anything). Still, since the question is quite old, it probably won't get much attention now. Not that there's anything wrong with Andrew's answer, as I said. But it would be nice to see this one at least in *second* place! :)

Comment: [*issual* seems less common than *isual*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=issual%2Cisual&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cissual%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cisual%3B%2Cc0) even though the latter is typically an error for *usual* or *visual*

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen *issual,* and OED doesn’t list it either. Collins **mentions** *issual,* but it's not yet actually included; they simply publish the submissions that they have received for consideration.

So no, it's not a word which has wide acceptance, even if it does appear in a number of Indian English publications.

More context would help, but in most cases *issue* can be used, which is a word with a far wider acceptability.

> **issue** *noun*
>   **2** [*mass noun*] the action of supplying or distributing an item for use, sale, or official purposes:
>   *the issue of notes by the Bank of England*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/issue)]

ODO does list *issuance* as a derivative form which can be used as the mass noun.

Comment: Of course, *issue* **can** be used, but that's not the question.

Comment: @Kris OK. Question answered.

Answer (score 2):

*Collins English Dictionary* New Word Suggestions:

> Definition of [ISSUAL](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/1038/ISSUAL)
>   Act of issuing.
>   (This word has been in use for some time now in **India**.) example sentences: (1) **Issual** of tender notifications have been delayed. (2) Ministry announced that the **issual** of passports to the applicants would be hastened. [emphasis added]

Comment: Could you include a link? Anything online to confirm this? I find that information quite staggering. I've checked. The word has not been approved by CED, it was submitted in 2012 and there are no comments or links confirming this "entry".

Comment: The word *issual* is a [new word submission](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/1038/ISSUAL) which has status **pending investigation**. It has **not** yet been included in the dictionary.

Comment: What @Andrew, Mari Lou said. This answer is grossly misleading, giving the impression that Collins might actually endorse the definition, which I suggest is vanishingly unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

As Tony mentioned in December:

> It is an Indian English word. It is widely used in official / government circles.

Here are some sources for that:

[*Pune Mirror*, Jan 7, 2011](http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Repository/getFiles.asp?Style=OliveXLib%3aLowLevelEntityToPrint_MIRRORNEW&Type=text/html&Locale=english-skin-custom&Path=PMIR/2011/01/07&ID=Ar00700)

> Staff shortage at Food Distribution Office hampers timely **issual** of ration cards and monitoring of illegal trade in food earmarked for fair price shops

[*samachar*, June 19, 2013](http://www.samachar.com/Hall-tickets-for-SSLC-supplementary-exams-on-June-21-and-22-ngtlLKgighb.html)

> Hall tickets for SSLC supplementary exams on June 21 and 22
>   Keywords: SSLC special supplementary examinations, Hall tickets **issual**, Tiruchi

Those are some examples of the usage in our media.

*meta*: The site doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links!?

Comment: Hi Siva. Could you also explain in your answer what you found in the links? Because links don't last forever!

Comment: Meta: This is because you are a [new user](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Once you earn 10 reputation, this restriction will be lifted.

Comment: Funny. One answer states it's in use in India, but gets criticized for having no sources. This answer cites the sources, but get's criticized for leaving out the one-line answer that those sources prove. I'll add it to this answer, so that the two are effectively merged.

Answer (score 1):

It is an Indian English word.  It is widely used in official / government circles.

Comment: A previous answer already indicated that it is in use in Indian English. Can you provide links or citations to examples?

Comment: What choster said. I've not been able to find any significant usages that can't just be put down to illiteracy. No disrespect to Indian English as such, but there are a lot of people in India with limited knowledge of English. They just make this mistake more often than other nationals not writing in their native language.

Answer (score -1):

There are seven issuals against my name. They cannot be renewed online. May I request that these be renewed as I am unable to come to the library this week.

Thanks and regards,

NOTE: One could also use "There are seven titles issued against my name" but the issued items could be books, CDs, journals, magazines etc, so "titles" itself in inappropriate word. So the word issuals is handy as a noun that denotes either "act of issuing" or "items issued". Very common usage in India, I wonder how the sentence would be framed by native English speakers for the above context without using "issued items" which will sound officious.